# calculating DC value from positive frequency with its DC undefined

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency-response

Is there a way of calculating DC value from just the positive frequency that has its DC undefined ? Simply if we remove the DC and the negative frequency components of the signal is there a way to reconstruct it from just the positive frequency values.

Comment: Is it from a signal or a response of a physical system? Because for the latter you would have that the negative frequencies are the complex conjugate of the positive frequencies and you might be able to find the DC (0 Hz) value by extrapolating.

Comment: It is a response of a physical system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume you have the signal

$$x(t)=a+b\cos(\omega_0t)\tag{1}$$

with some non-zero real-valued constants $a$ and $b$. Now remove DC and the negative frequencies to obtain

$$x'(t)=\frac{b}{2}e^{j\omega_0t}\tag{2}$$

Can you calculate the value $a$ from $(2)$?

Comment: no I can't calculate value a from 2.

Comment: @rand1: Right, that's the point. I hope this answers your question.